# System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.' using protobuf-net.Grpc

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, .net-8.0, protobuf-net.grpc

I'm getting this error message "Specified method is not supported." whe using protobuf-het.Grpc

I have this Client

```
public class AddressClient
{

    private IAddressService _grpcService;
    public AddressClient(IAddressService grpcService)
    {
        _grpcService = grpcService;
    }

    public AddressClient() {

        GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2 = true;
        var http = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7185");
        _grpcService = http.CreateGrpcService<IAddressService>();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResultDTO<List<AddressModel>>> GetAddresses()
    {
        try
        {
            return await _grpcService.GetAsync(new AddressModel());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this Service

```
public class AddressService : IAddressService
{
    private readonly AddressStore _addressStore;
    public AddressService(AddressStore addressStore) { 
        _addressStore = addressStore ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(addressStore));
    }
public async ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<List<AddressModel>>> GetAsync(AddressModel addressModel)
{
    try
    {
        var data = await _addressStore.GetAllAsync();
        return new ActionResultDTO<List<AddressModel>> { Data = data, Message = $"Listed Addresses Sucessfuly", Success = true };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ActionResultDTO<List<AddressModel>> { Data = null, Message = ex.Message, Success = false };
    }
}
}
[Service(name:"AddressService")]
public interface IAddressService : IBaseService<AddressModel, AddressFilterDTO>
{

}

public interface IBaseService<T, FilterType> where T : class
{
    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<T>> CreateAsync(T model);

    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<T>> UpdateAsync(T model);

    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<T>> DeleteAsync(T model);

    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<List<T>>> GetAsync(T model);

    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<T>> GetByIdAsync(int id);

    ValueTask<ActionResultDTO<List<T>>> GetFilterAsync(FilterType filter);
}
```

I'm trying to connect to the service using a the GRPC Client and getting that error message
Also the Address Model, inherits from a class name base model those two look like this.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class AddressModel : BaseModel
{
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public string? District { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public string? City { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public string? State { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(8)]
    public string? ZipCode { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(9)]
    public string? Latitude { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public string? Longitude { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public string? Line1 { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(12)]
    public string? line2 { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add full exception text.

Answer (score 0):

This is just hints from the code provided

- Use [ServiceContract] for class and [OperationContract] for members.
- Use [DataContract] instead of [ProtoContract].
- Try to simplify the generics at least to start with a simple working prototype.

A full example of working gRpc is here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Coder